# Getting Key in Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, collectors

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> myValues;

myValues.entrySet().stream.collect(
    Collectors.toMap(entry -> getActualKey(entry.getKey()),
                     entry -> doCalculation(entry.getValue()))
                     );
```

Is there a way for me to get the Key, inside the doCalculation function? I know I can pass `getActualKey(entry.getKey())` again as a parameter to doCalculation, but I just don't want to repeat the same function twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map your entries to a new intermediate entry with your derived key, then pass the value pair to `doCalculation()`:

```
myValues.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new SimpleEntry<>(getActualKey(e.getKey()), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> doCalculation(e.getKey(), e.getValue())));
```